# Installing OTRS 3.2 in Windows

Tags: html, mysql, perl, apache, otrs

I have downloaded the installer of OTRS 3.2 for windows here (https://portal.otrs.com/otrs/public.pl?Action=PublicDownloads#) I have seen that installing the OTRS requires Active Perl installed.So i download Active Perl and install. After that I continue installing the OTRS , I haven't seen any error message appear but when i finish the installation and launch the application, a blank page appear in my browser.  I think I need something that need to setup in my computer before running the the web installer.

Can someone please give some step by step procedure installing OTRS in my Windows Laptop.

I am not familiar with this application so please give me some hints for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably better off going to their support forum at http://forums.otterhub.org/

Comment: Can you please indicate if you are using IIS or apache? also MSSQL or mysql? what version of active perl?

Answer (score 1):

OTRS on Windows starts a web server on port 80. Sometimes Skype 'occupies' port 80 which means that the OTRS web server can't take that port and use it. Then you'll see a blank page, just as you described.

The solution is to quit Skype and restart the web server. Now if you start skype afterwards, it will no longer occupy port 80.
The OTRS web server is a service called `Apache` or `World Wide Web Publishing Service` if you used ActiveState Perl.

Can you let me know if you indeed had Skype running?